# Inserting value in input box using innerHTML and GetElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I have added a row using javascript. Now I want the new columns's value to be picked from the input box text by id. There's some sort of error in it, which I'm unable to get.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function addtosubtotal() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(2);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = getElementById("cid");
    cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("name");
        }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="myTable" >
    <tr>
        <td>S. No</td>
        <td>Item Name</td>
        <td>Subtotal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="cid" name="id" /> </td>
        <td><button onclick="addtosubtotal()" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementById("cid")`  -> `document.getElementById("id")` + other things. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/wbddLfnz/

Comment: that was a typing error.. corrected.. it isn't working yet..

Comment: The jsfiddle link i gave you works. If it does not do what you want it to do, please edit your question and explain clearly what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an id for the input `name`:

`<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />`

So you wont get it by id

You can also combine the two statements in your JavaScript if you want to

```
<script>
function addtosubtotal() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(2);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = document.getElementById("cid").value;
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value;
        }
</script>
```